# Error getting the correct Python3 dependency

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6, python-3.7, amazon-linux, condor

I get this error when trying to install HTCondor on Amazon Linux 2 instance:

```
Error: Package: python3-condor-8.8.15-1.el7.x86_64 (htcondor-stable)
       Requires: libpython3.6m.so.1.0()(64bit)
```

I tried installing python 3.6 on my own (given that the one installed was 3.7) and in /usr/local/lib I have libpython3.6m.so.1.0. Is this the same as libpython3.6m.so.1.0()(64bit)?

Adding it to the LD Library Path (export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/) doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to install HTCondor from the CentOS 7 repositories on Amazon Linux 2. Please use the amzn2 repository. It should be as easy as replacing "el7" with "amzn2" in your yum repo file. The amzn2 binaries are compiled against the Python 3.7 included in Amazon Linux 2.